# Функция для перемешивания содержимого массива во всех возможный вариантах

Tags: алгоритм, любой-язык

Например есть массив `var mas = int[1,2,3,4,5,...,n]`. Количество вариантов расположения элементов будет `n!`. Как получить все возможные варианты?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простая итеративная реализация алгоритма на C++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    const int n=4;
    int a[n];
    int i,j,k,i1,i2;
    int temp;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) a[i]=i+1;
    for(;;) {
        for(i=0; i<n; i++) cout << a[i] << " ";
        cout << '\n';
        for(j=n-1; j>0; j--)
            if(a[j]>a[j-1]) break;
        if(j==0) return 0;
        j--;
        for(k=n-1; k>j; k--) {
            if(a[k]>a[j]) {
                temp=a[k];
                a[k]=a[j];
                a[j]=temp;
                break;
            }
        }
        for(i1=j+1,i2=n-1; i1<i2; i1++,i2--) {
            temp=a[i1];
            a[i1]=a[i2];
            a[i2]=temp;
        }
    }
}
```